# Web2py - Erro ao utilizar SQLFORM.factory()

Tags: python, sqlite, framework, web2py

Não consigo resolver um ***erro*** que aparece quando tento expor um formulário para duas tabelas do `SQLite`.

O erro é o seguinte:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
>           exec(ccode, environment)
>         File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py/applications/vr/controllers/default.py", line 101, in 
>         File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 409, in 
>           self._caller = lambda f: f()
>         File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py/applications/vr/controllers/default.py", line 55, in register_student
>           form = SQLFORM.factory(db.Pessoa,db.Aluno)
>         File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py/gluon/sqlhtml.py", line 1922, in factory
>           return SQLFORM(DAL(None).define_table(table_name, *[field.clone() for field in fields]),
>       AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'clone'

Meu controller e meu model são os seguintes:

***Model:***

```
    db.define_table('Pessoa',
    Field('nome',required=True,notnull=True),
    Field('cpf',required=False,notnull=True,length=11),
    Field('data_de_nascimento',type='date',required=False,notnull=True),
    Field('cep',notnull=True,length=8),
    Field('uf',notnull=True,length=2),
    Field('pai',notnull=True),
    Field('mae',notnull=True),
    Field('identidade',notnull=True,length=13),
    Field('expedicao_identidade',type='date',required=False,notnull=True),
    Field('tipo_sanguineo',notnull=True,length=3),
    Field('orgao_emissor',notnull=True,length=20),
    Field('doador',type='boolean', notnull=True),
    Field('origem',notnull=True,length=40),
    Field('observacao',notnull=True),
    auth.signature,
)

db.define_table('Aluno',
    Field('pessoa_id', 'reference Pessoa', writable=False, readable=False),
    # Field('nota_fiscal_id', 'reference Nota_fiscal', writable=False, readable=False),
    Field('matricula', notnull=True, length=7),
    Field('renach', notnull=True, length=40),
    Field('categoria', notnull=True, length=5),
    Field('servico', notnull=True),
    Field('status', notnull=True),
    auth.signature,
)
```

***Controller:***

```
def register_student():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(db.Pessoa,db.Aluno)

    if form.process().accepted:

        id = db.Pessoa.insert(**db.Pessoa._filter_fields(form.vars))
        form.vars.client=id
        id = db.Aluno.insert(**db.Aluno._filter_fields(form.vars))
        response.flash='Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!'

    return dict(form=form)
```

Fiz tudo isso baseado na documentação oficial da `Framework`. Se alguém souber me ajudar ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um problema presente nas duas versões mais recentes: 2.15.1 e 2.15.2.
Sendo que a segunda saiu para corrigir a primeira depois de alguns dias.
Dentro de alguns dias teremos uma nova versão corrigindo isso.
Enquanto isso você pode usar a versão anterior mais estável, 2.14.6.

[Web2py 2.14.6](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/R-2.14.6)

Answer (score 0):

Quando tento abrir o web2py acontece isso Carlos:

```
python web2py.py -a 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web2py.py", line 21, in <module>
    import gluon.widget
  File "/home/joao/Desktop/web2py-R-2.14.6/gluon/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    "You can also download a complete copy from http://www.web2py.com."
RuntimeError: web2py depends on pydal, which apparently you have not installed.
Probably you cloned the repository using git without '--recursive'
To fix this, please run (from inside your web2py folder):

     git submodule update --init --recursive

You can also download a complete copy from http://www.web2py.com.
```

E quando tento fazer o que ele recomenda, tenho que dar clone no repositório e é clonado a versão atual...